# Unable to enable/disable ASP.net Button uisng C# in the backend dynamically in timer_tick method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

In the below code , I want Button1 to be disabled until timer count down to "sdur" minutes say 3 minutes. But The button behavior is not changing. Please help. I also tried Button1.Enabled=true; still no effect. Thanks in advance

```
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rem_minutes = (Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;
    if (sdur <rem_minutes)
        Button1.Attributes.Add("Enabled", "False");

    else
        Button1.Attributes.Add("Enabled", "True");
    if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
    {
        lblTimer.Text = string.Format("Time Left: 00:{0}:{1}", ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes).ToString(), ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds).ToString());

    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Response.Redirect("Logout.aspx");
    }      
}
```

I tried in java script too.

```
    htmlTable.Append(" <script> var seconds = " + ttime + "; function secondPassed() { var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; if (remainingSeconds < 10) { remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds; }  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Time Left :- ' + minutes + ':' + remainingSeconds; if (seconds == 0) { clearInterval(countdownTimer) ; document.getElementById('Button1').click() ; } else  { seconds--; } if(minutes<=" + sdur + ") { document.getElementById('Button1').disabled=false; }  } var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000); </script>");
```

Comment: use the debugger and step through the code.. the Timer Gets triggered based on the `timer1_tick event and Interval` perhaps you can see where you are going wrong when stepping through the code.. also `I think you should put the button inside the content template so it will disabled when the update panel is updated. if you are using updatepanel`

Comment: This code will only run on the server-side, and will not affect the client-side until they refresh the page.

Comment: i used the debugger, The logic is working fine. I think as Rick said, until it refresh the page it is not affecting. So what is the solution @Rick?

Comment: Are you using MVC or Web form ? because there is different way to refresh depending on

Comment: You probably want to do this in javascript. You will still need to check on the server if the operation is allowed because a clever user can manipulate the javascript to change the timeout and button availability.

Comment: I am using Web form. i tried in Java script too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the OnTick event of your timer that automaticaly postback:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="CodeBehindFunction" >
</asp:Timer>
```

and in the c# code behind :

```
protected void CodeBehindFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Get_timeElapsed() > timeOut)
        btnMAJ.Enable = false;
}
```

This works for me.

But the best is to use client side programming (javascript or whatever works for you) so you wont have to post back too often.